# None of these files exist - Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react-native project in expo, when I started the project the following error appeared:

```
None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\DatePicker\DatePickerIOS(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.svg|.svg)
  * node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\DatePicker\DatePickerIOS\index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.svg|.svg)
  15 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';    
  16 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
> 17 | import typeof DatePickerIOS from './Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS';
     |                                   ^
  18 | import typeof DrawerLayoutAndroid from './Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid';    
  19 | import typeof FlatList from './Libraries/Lists/FlatList';
  20 | import typeof Image from './Libraries/Image/Image';
```

I don't use this DatePickerIOS anywhere

I tried to reset the cache, delete node_modules, delete this "DatePickerIOS" inside node_modules, but error appears everywhere, I don't think it's just that

Comment: Would you share package.json and the project structure (a screenshot from your project workspace)?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this particular issue by upgrading to react-native 0.72.0.